# How to repeat a pattern in an MS Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a MS Access database and in it are two tables called [Pattern] and [Element].

The following example's show the tables and their respective datatype.

Table 1: [Pattern]

```
patternID - key
pStart - short date
pEnd - short date
```

Table 2: [Element]

```
elementID - key
patternID
text -text(2)
```

I want to create a query where it will repeat the pattern contained within the text field of the element table. For example

for patternID = 1 there are 4 elementID entries with the text values 1,2,3,4

How do I get a query to repeat 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4 for as long as the difference between the two dates, pStart and pEnd in the pattern table?

Hopefully this makes sense, thanks in advance. I usually work in Excel so Access is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a number or factor table with one field with integers from 0 to at least the maximum day count you will have.

Then you can create the first Cartesian query:

```
Select 
    patternID
From 
    Pattern,
    Factors
Where
    DateAdd("d", [Factor], [pStart]) <= pEnd
```

Save this as, say, Patterns and create a second Cartesian query:

```
Select
    Element.patternID,
    Element.elementID,
    Element.Text
From
    Patterns,
    Element
Where
    Patterns.patternID = Element.patternID
Order By
    Element.patternID,
    Element.elementID,
    Element.Text
```

Comment: To anyone else trying this, just remove the line order by and everything below it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if you are doing this in the query designer or sql view. If your writing the sql, this might help:

```
select distinct E.text
from Element E, Pattern P
where E.patternID = P.patternID
AND p.Start <> p.End
```

Comment: Getting an error, E.text isn't part of an aggregate function?

Comment: I've revised the code in my answer you could try that and see if returns what you're wanting to see.

Comment: Hi, that shows 1,2,3,4 but doesn't repeat afterwords. I'm going to go to bed and the in the morning I'll play around with your two approaches to see where I get. Thanks for your help, I've already learnt a few things!

Comment: Sounds good. The last thing I might recommend is removing the distinct, if you want it to repeat. Good luck!